# I have problems with Css and file path

Tags: css, filepath

so i'm making this project and i have to use html, css, php, etc...
My problem is that if one day i'm working with a file css and i have a feedback from the file the day after the same file without changing anything isn't working anymore and i don't understand why.
As first thing i tried to copy the file change the name and keep the location the same and it work until i don't close the project and re-open the day after and it'annoying to change every day all the css file to work with them. And some file didn't work even doing this.

```
<link href="../Stylesheet/Video.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this is an exemple of how i link a css file to html, nothing too complicated. As editor i'm using the free version of Sublime Text and some part of the code i took from Bootstrap.
Thanks for the help.
this is the last file css i used:

```
.logo_canale {
border-radius: 50%;
 }

  .form-text {

background:#0dcaf070;
margin-bottom: 2rem;

 }

   .form-text .title {

font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;

 }

.data {
font-size: 20px;
height: 1rem;   
margin: 1rem 0;
  }

 .btn-close {
position: absolute;
right: 2rem;

 }

   .show-btn {
background: #fff;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 500;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

 .show-btn{
display: block;
 }

  .show-btn {
position: relative;
left: 8rem;
  }

 .Pop-up{
position: fixed;
top: 10rem;
left: 45rem;
  }

  .hidden-check{
display: none;
  }

  .Pop-up {
display: none;
background: #fff;
width: 600px;
padding: 30px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

   #show:checked ~ .Pop-up{
display: block;
   }

   .Buttons{

margin-bottom: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
   }
```

and no matter what i try to change it will not give a feedback, i can literally cancel the file and it will still work like i saved yesterday.

Comment: It is not very common your ```html``` file sits deeper than your ```css```,  try: ```<link href="./Stylesheet/Video.css" rel="stylesheet">```.

Comment: I wanted to post an image on hoe tmy project was organized, but since i'm new on the site i still can't post images so i try to explain with words: I have a folder where to put everything then a folder with html and a folder with css that are separate that why i use  ../Stylesheet/Video.css

Comment: Do you have a ```404``` error in the console for this specific stylesheet?

Comment: no i tried to look but nothing

Comment: So no error? Post the styles that are not being applied from that file in your question.

Comment: Comment that you are using PHP, is there any condition to show that style? In the response you get in the browser, does it show that line? and if you try to enter the style path directly, does it work?

Comment: there are no condition to show the style, and if i put the code directly in the html or php pages using <style> it works

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS file is present in the same folder where is HTML file is present then we don't have to give the path of the file of CSS in HTML .we just have to enter the following line

But CSS and HTML file are present in the different folder we have to enter the path4

Comment: yeah i kown that, they are not in the same folder